# Power saving mode causes no network connection when app returns from background

Tags: android, networking, broadcastreceiver

I use an observer pattern to monitor when there is a change in network connectivity. The issue I am experiencing is that if power saving mode is enabled on any device, returning from the background to the foreground of my application will trigger "no network" momentarily when checking for connectivity. Because of the nature of observer pattern, this change will bring up my no connection dialog, even though milliseconds later a connection is restored.

The connection signal remains strong when returning to the app from the background, but for some reason power saving mode tricks the system into thinking there is no connection when there is. How do I control this? Is there some sort of way to ignore checking for connectivity if power saving mode is active?

Here is my network observer class. I register receivers throughout my app and utilize the app's Activity lifecycle to determine when I should be listening for changes in network and when I should not. Thanks in advance!

```
public class NetworkReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = NetworkReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final List<NetworkStatusObserver> mObserverList = new ArrayList<>();
    private static boolean isNetworkConnected = true;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Logger.i(TAG, "onReceive() broadcast");
        boolean disconnected = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
        boolean isNetworkConnectedCurrent;

        if (disconnected) {
            isNetworkConnectedCurrent = false;
        } else {
            NetworkInfo networkInfo;

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 17) {
                networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            } else {
                ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            }

            isNetworkConnectedCurrent = !FrameworkUtils.checkIfNull(networkInfo) && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        }

        if (isNetworkConnectedCurrent != isNetworkConnected) {
            isNetworkConnected = isNetworkConnectedCurrent;
            Logger.d(TAG, "NetworkStatus.onReceive - isNetworkConnected: " + isNetworkConnected);
            notifyObservers(isNetworkConnected);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Lets all {@link NetworkStatusObserver}s know if the DEVICE is connected to a network.
     *
     * @param isNetworkConnectedCurrent
     */
    private void notifyObservers(Boolean isNetworkConnectedCurrent) {
        for (NetworkStatusObserver networkStatusObserver : mObserverList) {
            networkStatusObserver.notifyConnectionChange(isNetworkConnectedCurrent);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add observer to observer list
     *
     * @param observer
     */
    public void addObserver(NetworkStatusObserver observer) {
        mObserverList.add(observer);
    }

    /**
     * Remove observer from observer list
     *
     * @param observer
     */
    public void removeObserver(NetworkStatusObserver observer) {
        mObserverList.remove(observer);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve observer list size
     *
     * @return
     */
    public int getObserverSize() {
        return mObserverList.size();
    }

    /**
     * Check if receiver is added to observer list
     *
     * @param observer
     * @return
     */
    public boolean contains(NetworkStatusObserver observer) {
        return mObserverList.contains(observer);
    }

    /**
     * Method is used to print observer list
     */
    public void printObserverList() {
        Logger.i(TAG, "===== PRINT OBSERVER LIST ===== ");
        for (int i = 0; i < mObserverList.size(); i++) {
            Logger.i(TAG, String.format("item(%d): %s", i, mObserverList.get(i).toString()));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Interface for monitoring network status change
     */
    public interface NetworkStatusObserver {
        void notifyConnectionChange(boolean isConnected);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is happening to me as well. Did you get any solution ?

Comment: @MobileAppDeveloper this was a while ago on a project I no longer work on, but I believe I ended up doing a hack (work around solution). I would flag the connection change, and then wait an arbitrary amount of time, e.g. 3 seconds, and if the there was still no active connection I would proceed with displaying that there is no connection. The arbitrary time was the shortest amount of time I was noticing the swap in network connection due to power saving. Unfortunately, I have no better solution than this.